# Laravel Elixir not working properly on Ubuntu

Tags: css, ubuntu, sass, laravel-5.1, laravel-elixir

I have simple **SCSS** file:

```
@import '../template_outgame.scss';

div#main-container {
    div#content {
        div#inside {
            table#games-table {
                tr {
                    th {
                        @extend .text-center;
                    }

                    td {
                        &:nth-child(3), &:nth-child(4), &:nth-child(5) {
                            @extend .text-center;
                        }

                        img {
                            @include border(1px solid #777);
                            display: block;
                            margin: auto;
                            opacity: .8;
                            width: 50px;
                        }
                        img:hover {
                            border-color: #888;
                            opacity: 1;
                        }

                        div.map-name {
                            font-size: 11px;
                            margin-top: 2px;
                            line-height: .93;
                        }

                        form {
                            input[type="submit"] {
                                float: none;
                                max-width: 150px;
                                min-width: 48px;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute `gulp` on my laptop (Win7) it's working fine. But when I run `gulp` on my Ubuntu server this part of code

```
&:nth-child(3), &:nth-child(4), &:nth-child(5) {
    @extend .text-center;
}
```

compile wrong.

Only for third child have `text-align: center;` style. Child 4 and 5 don't have this style and they are sad. `th` element above working fine too. What I do wrong?

`template_outgame.scss` file: http://pastebin.com/FhfeJbZW

`global.scss` file: http://pastebin.com/eeVsjMJg

`_bootstrap.scss` is Sass Bootstrap file

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: @alirezasafian I separate sass files and it's my code. Do you want gulp file? Or template_outgame.scss?

Comment: First, I want to check your sass files.

Comment: @alirezasafian so I edit my question. I don't understand why on Windows compile ok but on Ubuntu not.

Comment: I check your sass. [It works](http://sassmeister.com/gist/e9f6e5512a95c00f1483). Can you check output of css?

Comment: Of course, thank you for your time. http://pastebin.com/tyqRr2rs <- my output CSS on Ubuntu. Do you want to see output CSS on Windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96971/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-ventaquil).